# White page when deploying Symfony2 Project

Tags: symfony

After I finished my project of `symfony`2 on windows I wanted to deploy it on a digitalocean server with Linux-Ubuntu OS. But there are some problems I can't figure them out. Please help me soon.

I uploaded the web folder files to folder html on server and other files (src , app , bin, vendor) to `www` folder. I also followed the instructions on config.php and solved the problems. But yet:

1- When I trying to type `url : ip_address/app.php/` on browser a white page comes. No page and No error!

2- When I want to clear the cache in production env using the putty this error happens. ( Unable to write in the "C:/wamp/www/my-project/app/cache/prod" directory) but there is no such problem when clearing on localhost (I think this problem is because of transferring the project from windows to linux)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some errors (maybe cache directory).

For testing open the file web/app_dev.php and comment this:

```
/*if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
*/
```

Now you can access your page via ip_address/app_dev.php/ and see errors. When you finish, **don't forget to uncomment** this.

If you have problems with cache, then I suggest you to upload code without cache directory. Then create this directory in the server and give it right permissions.

Comment: I do like you said. The problem of cache clearing solved but the app.php page is still white. No other idea?

Comment: When I add my ip address to app_dev.php and run that the page has no problem. What is the problem with the app.php?

Comment: Thank you a lot my friend. My problem solved after giving the writing permission to the cache folder.

Comment: Great. If the answer is usefull, then you can accept it.